# Swift lazy var inconsistent behavior

Tags: swift, xcode8, macos-sierra, lazy-initialization

I have encountered a very unusual problem with lazy initialization.

My application reads metadata from an mp4 file, edits some of the data, and writes it back to the file. In previous versions, I read all the data when the file was opened. In the current version, I have switched to lazy reading of the data to improve performance and lower the memory footprint. However, I have encountered a very sporadic but reproducible bug, in which a few bytes seem to be read incorrectly from the file during lazy initialization.

Here is the initialization code:

```
lazy var data: Data = { [unowned self] in self.readDataFromFile() }()

func readDataFromFile() -> Data {
    guard let file = fileHandle else { return Data() }
    file.seek(toFileOffset: dataFilePointer)
    let data = file.readData(ofLength: dataCountInFile)

    print(Pointer: \(dataFilePointer)" + " Data: " + data.hexBytes(length: 32))

    return data
}
```

The print statement was added to debug this problem. The fileHandle is a FileHandle object which I create when the file is selected.  The dataFilePointer and dataCountInFile variables are set when the file is opened, by parsing the file for the pointers to the data.

When I read from the file for the first time, this is what I see in the log:

Pointer: 6808113917 Data: 14600000 1EA70000 12FB0000 19260000 12E20000

If I stop app without writing any data to the file, and then restart, not doing anything else, this is what I see in the log:

Pointer: 6808113917 Data: CFCB378C CFCBCDDB 00015F90 4B4231AA 55C40000

This is actually the correct data. Subsequent running of the app consistently shows the correct data.

I have put breakpoints at all points where the file could be written to verify that no data is written to the file.

Additional observations:

1. This bug only occurs with a few selected files. The vast majority of
   files are read correctly.
2. This bug only occurs with Release build configuration. It does not occur in Debug configuration. That is why
   I have had to use the print statement to observe what is happening.
3. This bug does not occur if I do not initialize the data var lazily,
   i.e. if I immediately read the data from the file when the object is
   initialized.

I am having a difficult time understanding what could be causing this strange behavior.

Comment: My first suspicion would always be threading. Are you certain that `data` is being accessed for the first time on the main queue? You don't have any locking here, so two operations can modify `fileHandle` at the same time. Whether that actually happened would be very timing depending, which is in keeping with your symptoms.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I am calculating some information from the movie data and loading cover art from the file on a global concurrent dispatch queue to improve loading speed.  By changing this to the main queue, the bug is fixed. However, this results in less responsiveness.  Is there any safe way to do any of this work off the main queue?

Comment: Don't use `lazy`. :D Seriously, it's just a convenience for one, very specific, very inflexible laziness pattern. Just implement your own with a backing store, and make it thread safe with standard thread-safety tools (like barriers and queues).

Comment: Hmm, I suspect you are correct, but I am pretty lazy myself. This will take a bit of re-engineering. Thanks much.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by dispatching the movie data and cover art loading to a serial queue, while maintaining the lazy pattern.  Like I said, I am pretty lazy.